# Sending notification about CFT created resource after creating the stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I want to send just the name of the S3 bucket created by Cloudformation. If i choose the SNS notification it will send the notification about complete CFT stack creation activity. Can we custom notification to just send the S3 bucket name to user
What are the options available to do this in AWS?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what can you do?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we custom notification to just send the S3 bucket name to user

Yes. Send the initial SNS notification to **lambda function**. The function will use AWS SDK to inspect the stack created, extract the bucket name, and pass it forward as needed.